# Will QML repaint the complete screen if any one QML item updates itself?

Tags: qt, qml

I have a QML application with multiple components over the screen. Among them two three components continuously update them self.

Can someone please let me know if QML will repaint the complete display/screen on update of any one item or it will repaint only the particular item which got changed ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I guess you have to read the [Qt Quick Scene Graph](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-visualcanvas-scenegraph.html) article